# Problems with Schema.org and Google Rich Snippets Test Tool

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets

I'm trying to get the Google Rich Snippets Tool to show stars on my post, and I can't find the mistake I apparently have done.

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http%3A%2F%2Fvpnstars.com%2Fvpn%2Fhide-my-ass%2F

I hope somebody maybe can guide me with above link.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The code below works, feel free to adapt it to your liking.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
    <h1 itemprop="name">Title</h1>
    <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
        <div class="rating">
        <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4.0">
        </div>
        <span itemprop="reviewCount">33</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Happy coding :)